# Force all <li> elements to be shown horizontally in a single line

Tags: html, css

I wish to show all my li elements as

ul

li1 li2 li3... (upto the width of the screen)

...li(n-1) lin

ul

i.e show them horizontally instead of vertically. 
I have seen so many questions related to it on SO, but somehow, even after trying many things, am not able to fix it for my html & css.

I am just a beginner with this so there might be a very basic mistake that I might have committed.

```
 <ul class="iconlist">
                <div class="inline">
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/profile/0.png"</a>
                        <h3><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">ABB</a></h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/profile/14.png"</a>    
                        <h3><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Siemens</a></h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/profile/0.png"</a>    
                        <h3><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Alstom</a></h3>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/profile/14.png"</a>
                        <h3><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Linde</a></h3>                    
                    </li>
                </div>
            </ul>


.iconlist{
list-style:none;
text-align:center;
padding:20px 0px 20px 0px;
clear:none;
float:left;
}

.inline
{
display:inline;
clear:none;
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have a `<div>` inside of an `<ul>`.  [The content model for `<ul>` is actually that specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/the-ul-element.html#the-ul-element)

Anyway, you want the `.iconlist` styles, but you want to apply them to the `<li>` elements, not the `<ul>`:

http://jsfiddle.net/vaQma/

Comment: @Explosion Pills Could you elaborate on the content model being that specific about `div`'s inside `li`? Because I believe this is wrong. On the page you're referencing, nothing is mentioned of a `div` inside an `li`. Also, I used the W3 validator (https://validator.w3.org/nu/) to validate a bit of HTML where I have an `li` with a `div` inside and it gives no errors or warnings. Also, the content model for a `li` clearly specifies 'flow content`, which includes `div`'s.

Comment: @J.P.tenBerge I think this answer has had a typo all these years -- I meant to say "You cannot have a `<div>` inside of a `<ul>`" which matches to the linked content model (one or more `li` elements) as well as the HTML in the question. `li` _does_ allow for `<div>` since it has Flow Content as its content model which includes `<div>`. I have corrected this.

Comment: That makes much more sense and I agree! Quick response too after all those years, well done. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping `li` with `div` is not valid. You just need to give `display:inline-block` to `li` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Heres how you do it:

```
.iconlist{
list-style:none;
text-align:center;
padding:20px 0px 20px 0px;
clear:none;
}

.iconlist li{
float:left;
}
```

Remove the div and the .inline class and your golden

Edit: display:inline-block; works too in place of float